# How do you count the days for each year between dates in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Assume 365 days a year.

Let's say from the dates of 12/1/2003 to 3/6/2008

What I want to see is how many days for each year within those dates.

The output should look something similar to this:

(2003 : 30 days) (2004 :365 days) (2005 :  365 days) (2006 :365 days) (2007:365 days) (2008 : 66 days)

Comment: You shouldn't delete the body of the question, you should use it to expound on what you're looking for.  I have NO idea just from the title what it is you want.

Comment: @MarkRansom I just edited the question hopefully this helps. PLEASE let me know if this is still unclear I will try my best to clarify if needed.

Comment: That is much better, I just have one remaining question - what about leap days?  Should 2004 be 365 days or 366?  Should 2008 be 66 days or 67?

Comment: @MarkRansom well I just did the math on the fly for the question to be more clear. My math isn't 100% correct I never understood leap years so I guess I don't need it for this situation. But if it makes it easier for code purposes use it.

Comment: Yes, I think it's easier if you include leap days because Python has the `datetime` type that does it for you automatically.  Let me know if the question gets reopened and I can whip up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module to manipulate dates:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current = datetime(2003, 12, 1)
end = datetime(2008, 3, 6) + timedelta(days=1)  # to include this final day

while current < end:
    next_year = current.replace(year=current.year + 1, month=1, day=1)
    if next_year < end:
        diff = next_year - current
    else:
        diff = end - current
    print(f'{current.year}: {diff.days} days')
    current = next_year
```

Output:

```
2003: 31 days
2004: 366 days
2005: 365 days
2006: 365 days
2007: 365 days
2008: 66 days
```

Comment: Thank you, @Mark Tolonen this was actually proven to be useful. Hopefully all is well, sorry for the late reply!